# How i can send array of objects from js to server?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, json

My class

```
[Serializable]
    public class VSpecialQualifiers
    {
        public VCD LivingStatus { get; set; }
        public VCD Relationship { get; set; }
        public string OnSetAge { get; set; }
    }
```

My js function

```
 $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {
                   'arr' : self.specialQualifiers
                }
          });
```

My serverMethod

```
[HttpPost]
        public JSONResult SaveProblem(object[] arr)
        {
          //i cant't cast to target type
        }
```

How i can pass the array of objects from js to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that works for me (to C# MVC on the back end).

...in the js:

```
var viewModel = new Object();
viewModel.Items = items; // items is a js array of objects
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    url: 'CONTROLLERNAME/ACTIONNAME', // replace as necessary here
    success: function (data) {
       // handle the return value, if any, here
    }
});
```

... in the controller, the signature here is all that matters:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ACTIONNAME(WorksheetVM inputModel) {
```

...and this is an associated ViewModel definition that works where WorksheetItemVM is the viewmodel DTO that contains the list of fields for each of the Js objects being passed :

```
public class WorksheetVM {
    public WorksheetItemVM[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that it matters but looks like you're using jQuery here which you should mention. Modern browsers have a JSON.stringify to turn the JavaScript array into a JSON string you can pass to the server. Older browsers don't have this so you need to include a JSON library like this one:

http://www.json.org/js.html

Then the same function will work in all browsers.

Once included, where you're passing data pass:

```
data: JSON.stringify(self.specialQualifiers);
```

Note here that I have no idea what `self.specialQualifiers` is but it should resolved to an array. You should do a `console.log` in Firefox's Firebug or Chrome / Safari's web inspector to make sure this is actually a real variable.

On your .net side you need to expect a string and then hava a .net library convert that string into an Array. You cannot pass native objects around via HTTP, only strings.

Comment: NB: The OP is tagged with `.net` and `mvc` - nowhere does he mention Java.

Comment: Thanks Sean, my response is still valid and I've replaced the word java with .net. Usually people who post web / BE confused questions are java people so my apologies!